# Search a word and date in a file content - shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting. Let me know how to write script for below senario.

A file named file1.txt contains some batch execution details and last 2 lines will contains success or failure of the job for the current date. Now I need to search the word success and followed by current date is there or not in last 2 lines of the file. if success with current date then set a variable $f1 with value 1 else 0. how can it do it?

sample last 2 lines of a file:

```
Trankey|BVCFG-B|989898|success|12/01/2016|01:34:07|12/01/2016|01:36:08
|file1.txt|ct32000001dev|transform
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quietly grep the last 2 lines of `file1.txt` for the current date.

```
tail -n 2 file1.txt | grep -q "success|$(date "+%d/%m/%Y")"
```

Set `f1` depending on whether `grep` found the pattern (return code of the last executed command in `$?`):

```
if $?   ## could replace this with the pipe line above
then
    f1=1
else
    f1=0
fi
```

That last one is weird. You could probably negate the value in `$?` some way, but in more general terms, success in bash is 0, not 1. (The other way around to how it's in C, C++, Java etc.)

So, if you go with that semantic for `f1`, things become easier:

```
f1=$?
```